# how can I update a variable V2, contained in a variable V1 at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass a generic variable, that is part of another variable.

I am passing hex data, this is an example of strings I use

```
# Initialize the variable value
var_value = '00'

push_op = '0f 11 13 01 ' + var_value + ' ac ff'
dump_op = '0f 13 13 15 ' + var_value + ' ac ff'

# change the variable so I can send the push and dump commands

var_value = ' 01 '
run_command(push_op)
# push_op still use 00 instead of 01

var_value = ' 12 '
run_command(dump_op)
# Same here    

var_value = ' 11 '
run_command(push_op)
# Same here too
```

The first assignment is correct, the var_value content is ' 00 ' as expected; but when I re-assign the variable, the content of the variable that contain `var_value` is not updated.

Is there a way to refresh the variable so it takes the updated content, or do I have to pass that variable rebuilding the string for the push and dump operators all the time?

Comment: You need to reassign value to first variable like `push_op=run_command(push_op)`

Comment: You need to rebuild your `push_op` and `dump_op` variables. The value of `var_value` is copied (not referenced in some way) at the time of assignment

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to pass the value by reference, I am forced to rebuild the string all the time.

Comment: Yes, you probably want to write helper functions that make this simpler. Then you can do something like `build_push_op('01')` to get the string for `push_op`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var_value = '00'
push_op = '0f 11 13 01 ' + var_value + ' ac ff'
```

Is merely creating a string, not much different than the hardcoded string `'0f 11 13 01 00 ac ff'`. As far as the interpreter cares, after this line executes `push_op` has nothing, and  will never have anything to do with `var_value`.

If `var_value` changes you will have to recreate `push_op` or any other string it was used in.

One possible approach:

```
push_op_template = '0f 11 13 01 {} ac ff'
dump_op_template = '0f 13 13 15 {} ac ff'

run_command(push_op_template.format('01'))
run_command(dump_op_template.format('12'))
run_command(push_op_template.format('11'))
```

Comment: I was trying too think of a way to do this with f-strings but this is just as good :-)

Comment: Nice usage of format; I did try also to use mutable strings (which does not exist in python, unless you use chars), but this seems to be more straightforward and readable

Comment: @paxdiablo f-strings are not very useful for usage as "templates" since they are interpolated at "definition" time, so in this case they will need be re-written every time the value changes

Comment: Yeah, that was the conclusion I came to. There are no f-strings where the string is an actual *variable* rather than a literal. Maybe that can come in 3.9+: `fmt = 'val is {x}' ; x = 42 ; print(f[fmt])` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not what you want but using a list seems to me solve the problem

```
push_op = ['0f 11 13 01 ', '00', ' ac ff']
push_op[1] = '01'
run_command(''.join(push_op))
```